# Why is my Django module missing?

Tags: python, django, dreamhost

I'm getting an error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named lxml
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.myurl.com/
Django Version: 1.2.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named lxml
Exception Location: /mypath/project/app/views.py in <module>, line 4
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.5.2
Python Path:    ['/usr/local/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/wsgi', '/usr/lib/python2.5', '/usr/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Numeric', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL', '/var/lib/python-support/python2.5', '/usr/lib/site-python', '/home/mysite/mysite.com', '/home/mysite/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 8 Dec 2010 22:59:32 -0500
```

I changed the names of the paths, obviously, but within my `home/mysite/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages folder`, I do have `lxml-2.3beta1-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg`, so how come Django can't find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the .egg isn't in `sys.path`. If you've installed it to a custom path then you'll need to add it in yourself.

Comment: Same way you add it to any other list.

Comment: sys.path.insert('/home/mysite/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages')

Is that it?

If so, I get an error:
An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py

Comment: Okay... but it's there in my PythonPath in the error screen. So what gives?

Comment: The .egg needs to be in `sys.path`.